# Error when implementing tensorflow high level api

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensor

I am trying to implement tensorflows provided high level api's, specifically the baseline classifier. However when trying to train the model, I get the following

Error:

```
NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Key baseline/bias not found in checkpoint
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT64], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]
```

Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

def digit_cross():
    # Number of classes, one class for each of 10 digits.
    num_classes = 10

    digit = datasets.load_digits()
    x = digit.data
    y = digit.target
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=.3, random_state=42)
    y_train_index = np.arange(y_train.size)

    train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
        x={"x": np.array(x_train)},
        y=np.array(y_train),
        num_epochs=None,
        shuffle=False)

    # Build BaselineClassifier
    classifier = tf.estimator.BaselineClassifier(n_classes=num_classes,
                                                 model_dir="./checkpoints_tutorial17-1/")

    # Fit model.
    classifier.train(train_input_fn)

digit_cross()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have a checkpoint in `model_dir="./checkpoints_tutorial17-1/"`, which is from another model and is not from a BaselineClassifier. To be specific, you have a checkpoint file and model.ckpt-* files in that folder.

As tensorflow documented:

> - model_dir: Directory to save model parameters, graph and etc. ***This can also be used to load checkpoints from the directory into a estimator to continue training a previously saved model.*** If PathLike object, the path will be resolved. If None, the model_dir in config will be used if set. If both are set, they must be same. If both are None, a temporary directory will be used.

Here, `BaselineClassifier` will first build a graph which uses `baseline/bias`. Then it finds out that there is a previous checkpoint in `model_dir`. It will try to load this checkpoint and you should see an info (if you've done `tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)`) saying something like

```
"INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from .../checkpoints_tutorial17-1\model.ckpt-..."
```

Because this checkpoint in `model_dir` is not from a `BaselineClassifier`, it won't have `baseline/bias`. `BaselineClassifier` cannot find it and will thus throw an error.